# Microsoft Azure Face Service - GDPR

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services, face, facial-identification

I'm conducting a DPIA for a class from the point of view of Microsoft proposing their Azure face service. I am a bit confused at how the service works.

Their cognitive services terms say:
"Cognitive Services customers own, and can manage and delete their customer data"

But the Face service page says:
As of January 2020, "no image will be stored".

So how does the service work? How can a client have stored trained models and data is Azure does not store any images? What does Microsoft actually store on their end?

Answer (score 0):

Face is only one of the "Cognitive Services" services: some services need data from your side, some are already pre-trained etc.

For Face in particular:

- As said in the documentation you mentioned, no image is stored for the run
- For the "Identification" operations in Face service, you have to create your "PersonGroup" and/or "LargePersonGroup" and create "persons" in it, then adding faces to these persons: in that case, you have to store things called "enrollment templates" which are calculated representations of the input face. See [Transparency Note for Azure Cognitive Services Face API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/transparency-note-azure-cognitive-services-face-api/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)). It is stored with a guid key (personGroupId) and the API has a Delete operation (see [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395245)) to remove those items.

[image: Face API Basics]